このサイトが衰退している状況に対して、何かすべきですか？
前の投稿にてお示しした通り、このサイトの衰退は著しいです。この状況に対して、私たちはどのように対応すべきでしょうか。
何もしなくとも良いでしょうか？ それとも、何か行なうべきでしょうか？ 行なうとするならば、例えばどのようなことが考えられますか？ 皆様のご意見をお聞かせ下さい。

コミュニティとして何をどこまでの範囲で行えるのでしょうか？例えば「新規ユーザー獲得のために広報活動を強化したい」となったとき、そのためにXの@jastackoverflowを積極的に動かしたり、SOのデザインの刷新に伴ってプレスリリースを出したりすることができるのでしょうか

@supa 現在、X（旧Twitter）の公式アカウントは、動かせません。
今後もおそらく変わらないでしょう。
過去の経緯は aki さんがチャットで共有して下さっています。
Xの件に限らず、Stack Exchange社の関与が必要な事柄が有ると、そこで進まなくなってしまいます。
基本的にユーザーだけで進められる範囲で行なうしか無いと思います。

ありがとうございます。aki さんの投稿も拝読しました。ユーザー主導で行うしかないとなると、具体的なアクションは一層難しくなりそうですね...。

「どうしたらよいか」は管理者なりスポンサーなりの決めることで、オイラたちユーザーは粛々とそれに従うだけです。まあ個人的意見を述べさせてもらうと、成り行きのまま衰退→誰も知らないところでひそかに消滅、で十分でしょう。
現に、過去にあった qa.atmarkit.co.jp とか social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/home/ とかも店をたたんでいます。個人が維持していた Q&A 掲示板もいっぱい消滅していますし、いくつか残っているものも流量は激減しています（どぼんさんとことか、はなちゃんさんとことか）
え、オイラ個人はどうするかって？　そこそこ流量が残っている限りにおいては ROM したり気が向いたら発言したりするでしょう。流量が減りすぎて、見ててつまらなくなったらアクセスしなくなるだけのことです。「発言しなきゃ」「質を向上させなきゃ」なんて高尚なモチベーションはオイラ個人にはまったくありません。
そういう活動がしたい人が頑張ることは大いに歓迎ですが、それを読者全員に義務付けしないでほしい・・・ってのが正直な感想です。それを押し付けた結果が現状である、とも言えそう。

前の投稿に意見回答を書いたように、必ずしも投稿数がKPI・KGIでは無いと思われますが、それでも数が減っているのは寂しい・盛り上げていきたいというのなら、別に運営に何かを求めなくても気負って特別に何かしようとしなくても、一人一人のユーザーだけで簡単に出来て、提唱されている目標(ヘルプのツアー記事にある以下の記述)には何ら矛盾しない、むしろ推奨されても良い対処がありますね。

目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。

つまり「『プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問』を自分で投稿する」ということです。
時々StackOverflow歴は長そうなのに割と初歩的な感じの質問がされたりするのを散見しますが、それらと同様にちょっとした疑問や課題であっても質問として投稿してみる感じですね。
ちょっと目先の変わった行動ではあるため、実態や結果として対策や行動に相応しいかどうか最初は違和感が出てくるかもしれませんが、臆することなく行って良いことだと考えられます。

あるいはこのMetaでの記事。
質問・回答・投票の仕方、まとめ


適切な質問かの討議：クイズ形式の質問


ヘルプによると自分の質問に回答することが積極的に推奨されているので、自分の知識をほかの人と共有する方法として問題ないと私は考えます (自分の質問に回答できますか?)。リンク先の創業者のブログ記事を読むと、ウィキやブログのような使い方が想定されています。

このサイトでは、クイズ形式であっても質問は可能です。ただし、質問と回答を同時に投稿したくない場合そのことを本文に書きましょう。投票はそのコンテンツのユニークさや情報エントロピーに基づいて回答と質問に投票されます。

引用記事はクイズ形式としていますが、本当にクイズだとちょっとあざといので、TIPSやFAQを書くような感じで良質で詳細な質問と回答のペアを同時に投稿してしまえば良い訳です。
例えて言えばQiitaやZennで知識・経験を公開したり、課題/疑問の解決過程を自由なフォーマットで記事にしているように、それらをQ&A形式に仕立ててStackOverflowに投稿するような感じですね。
とりあえず示せる例は2つくらいですが、そんな感じでちょっと踏み出す程度でも行動は出来るでしょう。

この手の問題に対して、利用者側から出来る事は正直ないと思います。Webサイトの質云々はおいといて、そもそも人の目に触れなければ人は入ってこないので、宣伝やSEO対策等が強いサイトに流れていきやすいのではないかと思っています。運営元がそのへん頑張りたいと思ってなければ、特に流れは変わらないと思います。
傾向的にリクルート系の会社を運営してたりする会社は、その辺り強い気がします。（人集めないと儲からないので、当たり前といえば当たり前ですが）
私自身はプログラミングについての情報を見たりするのは好きなので、時々記事サイトや質問サイトをいくつか流し見したりしていますが、単に判らない事聞きたいだけの人なら、多分検索上位で目に付いたサイトで適当に質問するだけなのではないでしょうか。
